# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: in Ecommerce project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I work with a Spring boot project and when I run, I get the following error,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userSecurityService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract Ecommerce.entities.User Ecommerce.repository.UserRepository.findByUsername(java.lang.String)!
```

I assume the last lines  are what is important in the error stack,

```
Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract Ecommerce.entities.User Ecommerce.repository.UserRepository.findByUsername(java.lang.String)!
```

I have the User repository provided below,

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

The user entity is also provided,

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;

    private String userName;

    private String password;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    private String phone;

    private boolean enabled = true;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserShipping> userShippingList;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserPayment> userPaymentList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Order> orderList;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>(); 


    // .............. 
    // more lines of code for overriding the methods 

}
```

What is the issue here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring JPA Repository, the auto-generated finders obey the naming convention as follows.

```
findBy<DataMember><Op>
```

`<Op>` can be Like,Between etc..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the name of the method `findByUsername` should match with the property in the user entity. In the user entity class, I have used,

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;

    private String userName;
}
```

After I changed to the `username` from the `userName`, the problem is solved. I have done this after consulting other `SOF` posts, but, I still seek for the better explanation.